# how to override g5-ere plugins files in main theme?

Tags: plugins

im uses the [g5-ere plugin](https://plugins.g5plus.net/ere/) in my site,
now I want to override some files to main theme.
i have tried but its not working.

Plugin path : **E:\xampp\htdocs\ike\wp-content\plugins\g5-ere\templates\property\submit-property\details.php**

Theme Path : **E:\xampp\htdocs\ike\wp-content\themes\mytheme\g5-ere\templates\property\submit-property\details.php**

Second Way - **E:\xampp\htdocs\ike\wp-content\themes\mytheme\g5ere\property\submit-property**

what mistake im doing here?

**[g5-ere Documentation](https://plugins.g5plus.net/ere/faq/)**

Comment: You'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. There's no guarantee that you *can* override a plugin in your theme. Whether this plugin allows it or not is a question for them. (Also, please note that third party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.)